# Paraview crashes when loading a saved state

Tags: paraview

I had results of 2 CFD simulations, which I visualized using Paraview. Let me name the 2 results as case A and case B. In principle I had to analyze same parameters for both the cases. Hence I named the states of case A and case B with the same name, but had saved them in entirely different folders. There were about 4 states for each of the case (with the same name). I was able to load the states without any problems until yesterday. Today when I tried to load the very same state that I was able to load yesterday, Paraview crashed. What could be the reason for this?
I thought the problem occurred as I had used the same names for the states of both the cases. Hence I even tried load them after renaming. Still I couldn't load. I also reinstalled Paraview from scratch. Yet it crashed when I tried to load the state. The version I am using is *5.7.0*

Comment: improve your question or ask on our discourse : https://discourse.paraview.org/

Comment: @MathieuWestphal I have improved my question

Comment: can you share your state files and data ? do you have an error message ?

Comment: I am sorry as I not allowed to share the state files. No error message is displayed. When I try loading the state file I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQKEl.jpg) and then in about 2-3 seconds Paraview shutsdown.

Comment: It's hard to help you then. Did anything change in your system ?

Comment: I had the results of the simulations of three cases (say case A, B and C) and had saved the corresponding state files on the desktop. This problem started to occur when I moved  all the files of case A from the desktop to D drive.

Comment: The paths are hardcoded in the statefile. Edit it to correct the paths.